# why in this loop it is appeard as finished but it is not until I press ctrl+c

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to sort this loop algorithmitically:

```
def tri(t,n):
    test= False
    while not(test):
        for i in range(0,n-1):
            if t[i]>t[i+1]:
                aux=t[i]
                t[i]=t[i+1]
                t[i+1]=aux
                test = True
                print(t,i)
        if not(t[i]>t[i+1]):
            test=False
    print(t)
    return t

from numpy import array
t=array([int]*5)
for i in range(5):
    t[i]=int(input("t"))
tri(t,5)
```

the loop appear in the terminal finsished but it is not until i press ctrl + c

Comment: Check the second `if`: What is so special about the last two elements of `t`?

Comment: Can you explain the use of your algorithm a little bit more? if you are trying to implement the bubble sort `if not(t[i]>t[i+1]): test=False` make it run infinitely since after the first iteration maximum item is set to the last element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add *break* to if in for loop

```
def tri(t,n):
    test= False
    while not(test):
        for i in range(0,n-1):
            if t[i]>t[i+1]:
                aux=t[i]
                t[i]=t[i+1]
                t[i+1]=aux
                test = True
                print(t,i)

                break #here

            if not(t[i]>t[i+1]):
                print('no')
                test=False
    print(t)
    return t

from numpy import array
t=array([int]*5)
for i in range(5):
    t[i]=int(input("t"))
tri(t,5)
```